# How can I used the JSON in Pay Simple API in asp.net mvc

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, paysimple

Anyone whose using Pay Simlpe API? I want to asked something about how to used it in asp.net MVC platform.

it's full of JSON, how can I used it in the asp.net? like adding a customer or paying a payment?? showing the list of the customer? How can I used the Json in a field? because thier example has a value, what if I used the value of the field. like that

Comment: Add more information pertaining to question.

Comment: I add more explanation

Comment: are you using pay simple??

Comment: Please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so that you will know what makes your question better to understand

Comment: okay sir I change my question